# How to remove installed third party product from root parition and reinstall it on a diferent partition?

Tags: redhat, partition, ibm

I am newbie to linux. I have read about drive/partition/volume of linux for better understanding of what I am about to deal with. Here is the situation.

I am a IBM BPM application developer and I inherited VM which is based on RHEL 6.6 64-bit OS. BPM is installed under root partition (/bpm). When I checked the disk space usage the root partition is filled up 100%. No space left.

I was told by a linux engineer that this is not a good practice at all. He asked me why this third party product is installed under root? He suggested me to create a separate partition/format it and re-install the product then mount it back to root file system. I am not even sure I understand him correctly.

What steps I need to take in order to remove installed BPM product out of root partition and re-install it under different partition(?)?

I'd appreciate your help on this matter.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way is to create the new partition, mount it somewhere else (say /mnt/bpm), copy all the data from the /bpm to /mnt/bpm (perhaps using rsync as in rsync -avP /bpm/ /mnt/bpm), then remount and test.  Perhaps something like this

```
# shutdown software first
# assume rootvg as name of root volume group
# and 20g as size required
lvcreate -L 20g -n bpm rootvg
mkfs -t ext4 -j -m 0 /dev/rootgv/bpm
mkdir -p /mnt/bpm
mount /dev/rootvg/bpm /mnt/bpm
rsync -avP /bpm/ /mnt/bpm
mv /bpm /bpm.org
umount /mnt/bpm
mkdir /bpm
mount /dev/rootvg/bpm /bpm
```

Now start the software and test.  If it works, you can now remove /bpm.org

```
cd /bpm
rm -rf *
cd /
rmdir /bpm
```

This last part may be verbose, but I like to do it to make sure I don't accidentally remove / or other directories.

This may be all that is required.  I've successfully used this procedure to move files across filesystems.

Comment: Thank you for your advice and step by step procedure. I will try that!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to follow the steps in the Knowledge Center topic [Uninstalling IBM Business Process Manager](http://ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFPJS_8.5.5/com.ibm.wbpm.imuc.doc/topics/tuninstall_bpm.html) and then using the [Interactive Installation and Configuration Guide](http://ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFPJS_8.5.5/com.ibm.wbpm.imuc.doc/topics/bpm_roadmap_form.html) to reinstall the product.

Most likely BPM was installed together with its databases in the same partition, and the database started to fill up the partition. This can be avoided by regularly [purging data in BPM](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/bpm/bpmjournal/1312_spriet/1312_spriet.html).